# On Production server codeigniter 3.1.2(PHP) Session Destroy automatically redirect from facebook graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session, redirect

codeigniter session destroy on redirect from graph APi facebook some time its work and some time it destroy session and take a user to login page

**Here is Config.php Session code**

```
$config['see_driver'] = 'database';
$config['see_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['see_expiration'] = 0;
$config['see_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['see_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['see_time_to_update'] = 10000;
$config['see_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

and this is how i am setting user session after login and authenticate from database in **User_controller.php**

```
private function __set_user_session($user)
    {
        if(isset($user))
        {
            $data = [
                'user_id' => $user['id'],
                'ilocal_user_id' => $user['ilocal_user_id'],
                'package_id' => $user['package_id'],
                'no_available_business' => $user['no_available_business'],
                'name' => $user['name']
             ];

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
    }
```

After face book connect and on redirect this method is called and its automatically redirect to user on login page i dont know why he is destroying a session

```
public function connect_facebook_account($business_id)
    {
        $this->__load_business($business_id);
        try
        {
            if(isset($this->data['business'] ))
            {
                $this->fb = new Facebook();
                $this->data['facebook_url'] =  $this->fb->get_login_url($business_id);
                if(isset($_GET['code']))
                {
                    $social_acccount_info = $this->fb->fetch_access_token();
                    if($social_acccount_info['status'] === TRUE)
                    {
                        $social_acccount_info['business_id'] = $business_id;
                        // save data of connected account
                        $this->__create_social_account($social_acccount_info);

                        redirect($this->session->social_page_redirect);
                    }
                }

                if (is_page_connected($business_id) === NULL)
                {
                    $this->data['pages'] = $this->fb->fetch_facebook_pages($business_id);
                }


            }

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('message', $e->getMessage() );
        }

    }
```

this code is working on fine on localhost and sometime also works on production server but most of the time it destroy session on production but working on local machine ?

any solution ?

Comment: May be you restart session somewhere in your code filter..

Comment: Is there a change you've bind session to screen resolution?

Comment: yes session is bind to screen @Yevgen

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';    
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';    
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;    
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;     
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;     
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 600;    
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Try this code in config.php
if $config['sess_expiration'] =0 it will redirect to your route which ever you mentioned. Set session time according to your convenient time in seconds and update in $config['sess_expiration'`enter code here`] = 3600 for 1 hour. if you want to update session time automatically then $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 600; should be in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent problem that I spent quite a bit of time tracking a few months ago.  This article includes a good workaround though not a full resolution... works like a charm, generally.

http://blog.thecodingbox.me/codeigniter-frequent-session-expiration-fix/

Comment: it would be great if you put some most important indeas and brief info from the article here into the answer along with the link as it might get broken in future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your config.php file, the correct array key is used; change:

```
$config['see_driver']
```

to

```
$config['sess_driver']
```

..and so on

Also make sure the session cookie name is not the same for all your environments, this could cause a session to be lost when developing locally and also checking the production/dev site.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```